# Spring BeanPostProcessor invoked 3 times

Tags: java, spring

I am doing a BeanPostProcessor implementation. My Bean PostProcessor executing 3 times. I am getting post processor invoked 2 times extra before init method. I am unable to find why it is happening. Please help me.

My code and configuration files are as

**BeanPostProcesssor implementatin**

```
public class BeanPP implements BeanPostProcessor{

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object o, String string) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("---before initialization ------");
        return o;
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object o, String string) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("----After initializaion ---- ");
        return o;
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }        
}
```

**Customer Bean**

```
public class Customer {        
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
      System.out.println("..getName.....");
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      System.out.println("..setName.....");
      this.name = name;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
      System.out.println("....Bean is going though init method");
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void destory(){
      System.out.println("....Bean is going to destroy.......");
  }
}
```

**Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name="customer")
    public Customer getCustomer(){
        return new Customer();
    }
    @Bean
    public BeanPP getPP(){
        return new BeanPP();
    }

}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Customer customer = (Customer)appContext.getBean("customer");
        customer.setName("test user ");
        System.out.println(".Name is .."+customer.getName());
    }
}
```

**Output**

---before initialization ------
----After initializaion ---- 
---before initialization ------
----After initializaion ---- 
---before initialization ------
....Bean is going though init method
----After initializaion ---- 
..setName.....
..getName.....
.Name is ..test user

Comment: You have 3 beans and it will be called for all of them. You have `AppConfig`, `Customer` and `BeanPP` all 3 of them are beans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Plain bean factories allow for programmatic registration of
>   post-processors, **applying to all beans created through this factory**.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html

You have defined 3 beans, AppConfig, customer and PP. The bean post processor will be executed after every bean creation. If you have 3 beans it will be executed 3 times.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name="customer")
    public Customer getCustomer(){
        return new Customer();
    }
    @Bean
    public BeanPP getPP(){
        return new BeanPP();
    }
}
```

@Configuration also define a bean, because it inheritance from @Component.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: Hello Reos, Thanks i got your point. Thanks for format my code. It was my first code. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put in `postProcessBeforeInitialization` to print out also the `Object o` class just to see which class calls the BeanPostProcessor (it may not be the `Customer` class, but some other object that Spring initiates, even the BeanPostProcessor itself).

```
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object o, String string) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("---before initialization ------ " + o..getClass().getName());
    return o;
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```